# First release with VS - a lot of output (not only an .exe), can I reduce?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, compilation

after compiling a simple console application project for release I get a lot of output:

- The .exe => thats fine, I need this for sure :)
- MyApp.exe.config => Im using and changing this, thats fine
- Some .dll files => these are the extern libraries Im using, I think thats fine too

Unknown:

- MyApp.pdb
- MyApp.vshost.exe
- MyApp.vshost.exe.config
- MyApp.vshost.exe.manifest
- log4net.xml => huh, the config for log4net is already in MyApp.exe.config, why is another log4net config xml here?

Can I delete some of them without getting later trouble? Can I add the .dll´s somehow *into* the .exe (so that I dont have to copy always all the .dll with the .exe)?

Comment: @Marco what do you mean with "client pcs"? Why are they there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected, and all have purposes - but you are right: you don't need any of the "unknown" files, and can delete them (and certainly don't need to distribute them). For info:

- MyApp.pdb is the debug symbols; useful for stacktrace, and for debugging later if problematic; you can disable this via the Debug Info option in the Advanced Build Settings dialog (Project Properties, Build, Advanced...) but I don't recommend it
- MyApp.vshost.* is the debugger host process; you can disable this by disabling the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option (Project Properties, Debug)
- log4net.xml is the intellisense comments - useful for IDE usage when adding references

Answer (score 1):

Those files aren't meant to be distributed to client pcs nor are useful for app to work properly: they're there (also) for debugging purpose.
If you want to "merge" dlls to your project, try using Microsoft utility [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630).

Answer (score 1):

When you build your solution in release configuration there will be no *.vshost.*., this is an executable for debug hosting process.

log4net.xml you can remove, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine deleting/not deploying most of them.
If the dll's are managed assemblies you can use [IlMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) which will add the dll's into the exe for you.